# Selenium uploads black image instead of image at specified path

Tags: python, selenium

I have a script running that uploads an image and clicks the submit button. When I go to view the image it seems that it has uploaded a black box and not the actual image. Whats going on?

Note: the post.image has a specified path set earlier. It wouldn't run unless the path led to an actual image or video.

Heres the code used:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@data-testid="media-attachment-add-photo"]').send_keys(post.image)
```

Comment: Doing it manually is also returning the same result i.e. black image ??

Comment: No, it works normally.